# How to test component before useEffect runs?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a useEffect hook that loads data and then modifies the state, which causes a re-render. I want to include a jest unit test for the way the component renders prior to the async behavior of useEffect completing. Is there a way to do this kind of test?

Comment: how does your component look like?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you do not want it to re render while setting the state.
In this case i think you can pass a blank []
useEffect(() => {},**[])**

If not then can you share piece or screenshot of your code, to understand it better ?

Comment: This is more suited as a comment rather than answer

Comment: I'm not trying to change the code. I just want to write a unit test for how the component renders BEFORE useEffect runs.